# How are random effects being included in the linear mixed model along with the concept behind their calculation

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I'm having difficulty in understanding the "process" that is going on behind how we are calculating all of our parameter estimates and how the random effects are used in our models.

To begin we can express the linear mixed model as:

$$y = X\beta + Zb + \epsilon \\b \sim  N(0, \psi_\theta),\ \epsilon \sim N(0,\Lambda_\theta)$$

Where $X\beta$ would represent the fixed effects and $Zb$ would be representative of the random effects. How are both sets of effects being estimated? What I mean by this is I get that we will be using maximum likelihood methods to estimate the parameters formally. But what is the process? Are we estimating the fixed effects $X\beta$ and the random effects $Zb$ separately and then bring them together in our model?

I was playing around in R to try and understand more, but I'm still stick in making the leap. Here is an output I got from fitting a LMM to the `iris` data set:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length + (1 + Sepal.Length |      Species)
   Data: iris

REML criterion at convergence: -66.7

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.76049 -0.54295 -0.08282  0.55066  2.74867 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name         Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Species  (Intercept)  0.24352  0.4935       
          Sepal.Length 0.01377  0.1173   0.40
 Residual              0.03091  0.1758       
Number of obs: 150, groups:  Species, 3

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   0.20829    0.33520   0.621
Sepal.Width   0.27272    0.05248   5.196
Sepal.Length  0.01796    0.07726   0.232

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Spl.Wd
Sepal.Width -0.116       
Sepal.Lngth  0.134 -0.279
> coef(ir_lme2)
$Species
           (Intercept) Sepal.Width Sepal.Length
setosa      -0.1400153   0.2727164  -0.10956019
versicolor   0.0573940   0.2727164   0.08658932
virginica    0.7074925   0.2727164   0.07684240

attr(,"class")
[1] "coef.mer
```

So I have `fixed effects` and `random effects` as can be seen at the bottom of the outputs.

With regards to the random effects I get that we "group" our observations and then use those groupings to get group estimates of our parameters which are the `random effects` below. Were those `random effects` estimated in isolation and if so how? Same question with respect to the `fixed effects`.  Another question is how are those `random effects` playing into the `fixed effect` estimates? Are the random effects contributing to the values we see in the fixed effects read outs?

I read previous articles on the site about the ideas:

[What is the difference between fixed effect, random effect and mixed effect models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode)

[What is a difference between random effects-, fixed effects- and marginal model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/what-is-a-difference-between-random-effects-fixed-effects-and-marginal-model)

I had also asked a previous question about this, but I might delete it because it is muddied in my confused understanding of the concept.

As you can see my head is all over and I'm very confused about how things are being put together in this model. Any help to clarify things would be appreciated.  Even in chat because I feel the things I'm not getting should be easy to clear up.

EDIT: So I attempted to get some clarification from a TA. In my example let's say we end up with the expression:

$$y = \beta_0 +\beta_{SW} \cdot SW + \beta_{SL} \cdot SL + (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2  \beta_{SL}SL)$$

where $\beta_i$ correspond to the fixed effects and $\alpha$ corresponds to the random effects, $SW =$ `sepal.width`, $SL =$ `sepal.length`, and $\alpha =$ `random effect from Species`.

So if I understand this correctly for the random effect of random slope, we would group by `species`, take all of the `Sepal.Length` values by species (let's use setosa as a concrete example), compute an estimate for the variance, use this estimate for the variance in a normal distribution $\alpha \sim N(0, \sigma_{setosa}^2)$ from which we would draw a random value for `Sepal.Length`, and then this would serve as the random factor $\alpha_2$ which we would multiply by $\beta_{SL}$ to get our value for the random slope?

Not looking for the precise mathematics yet, just an understanding.

Comment: Is your question about the process of estimation or about how to intuitively view the process of data generation?

Comment: It would be about the intuitive process. I know the mathematics will involve likelihood methods and get very messy. But if I don't understand intuitively what is happening I have no hope of getting the math.  Any more clarification on exact things let me know. I am also ready to go to the chat if it get's extended.

Comment: would something like the example at the end of this [question/answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/353590/164061) help? I could remake it based on the formulas that you have with the iris flowers.

Comment: oh my gosh. I didn't see this answer when I was looking. It explains a bit of what I'm trying to understand. But yes something along these lines would help. Because the expression you put at the very beginning of your explanation is what I'm trying to picture how it is working. As your illustration shows you have different intercepts and slopes, so how are those "lines" being made?

Comment: That example has only random intercepts. The slope is the same. So those "lines" are made by a (random) shift in vertical direction for points that belong to the same group.

Comment: An example of random slopes is shown [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/363859/164061) note the plot with the 35 different plots.

Comment: Do you get the expression $Zb$ if it would be a fixed effect? One source of confusion might be that $Z$ is a categorical variable, and so possibly it is difficult to imagine that.

Comment: Well if $Zb$ were a fixed effect then this would reduce the introductory linear model that we see in a first course on linear regressions and I could use OLS to estimate the parameters. I also didn't know that $Z$ always had to be a categorical variable (I'm assuming there is a continuous case, but that will be for the future).  So are the fixed effect and random effect being estimated separately? i.e we only take the fixed effect portion of our model, perform estimation. Then perform estimation on the random part of our model and then add both pieces together?

Comment: *"So are the fixed effect and random effect being estimated separately?"* The random effects are not coefficients that are being fitted/estimated like the coefficients for the fixed effects are fitted/estimated. They are nuisance parameters but they do not need to be explicitly fitted as described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/330097/164061). Only the variance or standard deviation is a parameter that is fitted.

Comment: So in your example of the 35 plots why were you able to demonstrate 35 different slopes if the random effect is not being fitted? With regards to the variance / standard deviation being fitted. What you're saying is that we take that variance and would add it to our variance for the errors, i.e $var(\epsilon_{ij}) =\sigma_b^2 + \sigma^2$ and that would contribute to being an estimate for the errors. Then we could perform our needed tests.

Comment: Those 35 slopes where not found with a mixed effects model but with a fixed effects model. But what the 35 slopes still do and makes them relate to mixed effects is that they illustrate that there is a variation in slope from participant to participant.

Comment: Then how did 35 different slopes get calculated? I thought it would be a case where $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X$ and $\beta_1$ would be a fixed value so the slopes would not differ.

Comment: 35 individual fits giving 35 different values of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$.

Comment: You've provided me with a bunch of resources, thank you. Let me take some time to review them and come back to this. Hopefully you'll still be around in a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of mixed models as a two stage modeling approach. Firstly, you fit a model irrespective of the random effects; secondly you model the effect for each level of the grouping factors (random effects) via an approach known as partial pooling, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/151800/32477) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/475549/demonstrating-complete-pooling-no-pooling-and-partial-pooling-regression-in-r) for some more explanations and details.
Finally, you adjust the fixed effects model based on the random effects. All of this happens together when running a mixed-effects model. Here is an example using the `sleepstudy` data in `R`:

```
> m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
> fixef(m)
(Intercept)        Days 
  251.40510    10.46729
```

Which is the same as this:

```
> m2 <- lm(Reaction ~ Days, data = sleepstudy)
> coef(m2)
(Intercept)        Days 
  251.40510    10.46729
```

Going back to the `lmer` model, the random slopes estimates are:

```
> ranef(m)
$Subject
    (Intercept)
308   40.783710
309  -77.849554
310  -63.108567
330    4.406442
331   10.216189
332    8.221238
333   16.500494
334   -2.996981
335  -45.282127
337   72.182686
349  -21.196249
350   14.111363
351   -7.862221
352   36.378425
369    7.036381
370   -6.362703
371   -3.294273
372   18.115747

with conditional variances for “Subject”
```

Now you adjust the average (fixed effect) intercept for each subject based on the estimated random effect, let's look at *Subject 308* as an example:

$251.40510 + 40.783710 = 292.1888$

The result can also be checked by looking at `coef(m)` as well:

```
> coef(m)
$Subject
    (Intercept)     Days
308    292.1888 10.46729
309    173.5556 10.46729
310    188.2965 10.46729
330    255.8115 10.46729
331    261.6213 10.46729
332    259.6263 10.46729
333    267.9056 10.46729
334    248.4081 10.46729
335    206.1230 10.46729
337    323.5878 10.46729
349    230.2089 10.46729
350    265.5165 10.46729
351    243.5429 10.46729
352    287.7835 10.46729
369    258.4415 10.46729
370    245.0424 10.46729
371    248.1108 10.46729
372    269.5209 10.46729
```

And now here's your example that also includes random slopes:

```
> m3 <- lmer(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length + 
         (1 + Sepal.Length |Species), data = iris)

> fixef(m3)
 (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Sepal.Length 
  0.20829042   0.27271644   0.01795717 

> ranef(m3)
$Species
           (Intercept) Sepal.Length
setosa      -0.3483057  -0.12751737
versicolor  -0.1508964   0.06863214
virginica    0.4992021   0.05888522

with conditional variances for “Species”
```

Let's combine the fixed and random intercept and slopes together for `setosa` as an example:

*Intercept*:

$0.20829042 - 0.3483057 = -0.1400153$

*Sepal.Width* stays the same (no adjustment, i.e. not included in random effect terms):

$0.27271644$

*Sepal.Length*:

$0.01795717 - 0.12751737 = -0.10956019$

Let's check with:

```
> coef(m3)
$Species
           (Intercept) Sepal.Width Sepal.Length
setosa      -0.1400153   0.2727164  -0.10956019
versicolor   0.0573940   0.2727164   0.08658932
virginica    0.7074925   0.2727164   0.07684240
```

Here is a good explanation and an example that is not too complicated to follow and easy to understand: https://m-clark.github.io/mixed-models-with-R/random_intercepts.html#the-mixed-model

Another helpful link understanding complete pooling, no pooling and partial pooling: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/06/plotting-partial-pooling-in-mixed-effects-models/

Comment: Aw man...I wish I gave you the bounty because your answer brings so much more clarity to the situation. One more question with regards to the random estimates. When we estimate the random effect (be it intercept, slopes), are we calculating it by "restricting" our data to the specific grouping and then calculating the parameter? For example in my model I restricted by species, so we restrict our data to the `setosa` species and perform the necessary calculations to get a slope and intercept and then those are the random effect slope and intercept we added to the fixed.

Comment: @dc3rd Have a look at the links above on complete pooling, no pooling and partial pooling. Suppose we have 10 subjects and 4 to 8 measurements for each subject. We can now calculate the mean of the whole dataset (complete pooling) which would give us a reliable estimate for the outcome but ignoring the contribution of each subject. Next, we could also calculate the mean for each subject and end up with 10 means (no pooling) which are likely not as reliable as well as susceptible to outliers since only 4 to 8 measurements went into the calculation [...]

Comment: [...] partial pooling is a "comprise" between complete pooling and no pooling in that it shrinks group observations with fewer observations or larger variances towards the complete pooling average. How exactly the group level estimates/adjustments for the random term components are calculated, I am not sure. For me this is all I know about this process conceptually. Here's is another link that visualizes this https://www.tjmahr.com/plotting-partial-pooling-in-mixed-effects-models/

Comment: I read your mixed models link from Clark...helped a lot. Will check these ones too. Thanks for the help my fellow Canuck.

Comment: No problem @dc3rd :D I am glad you found this information useful.

Answer (score 2):

The long and short of the answer is: yes, the random and fixed effects are calculated/estimated at the same time.  However, my sense is that you are not particularly interested in the mathematics behind that process.  Instead, it seems that you are looking for a conceptual understanding of the estimation process.  For this, it is OK to think of the processes happening separately.

And for this explanation, you would want to think of the data in groups.  But first start with everything in one big group; here we would obtain the fixed effects.  Now, inside of each group, we would obtain a solution for the remaining effects that weren't estimate in the big group (the random effects)...but, as we are just focusing on one group, these could also be seen as the "rest of the effects" (as opposed to the random effects).  In other words, within each group estimation, there is nothing "random" happening with regards to the solution.

Now, once you've done this for all groups, each group will have the same fixed effects estimates, and each group will have distinct effects estimates for all the other effects.  These are collectively the random effects.  If you wanted to, you could then take any one of your random effects, compile the by-group parameters into one data set, and the mean and variance of this is (approximately) the mean and variance reported for your random effect in the output above.

Again, to clarify, this is not how the actual estimation process obtains the parameters for the random effects (namely the mean and variance of the parameter), but it conceptually is what is "happening under the hood" of the engine generating these results.  (The estimation process uses a more sophisticate approach so as to obtain even better estimates for the variance and associated standard errors...and I will leave the explanation of that to someone else.)

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: I did. Thank you very much. I know there is more to it, but why dorwned myself in the mathematics if I have no idea of what is somewhat happening conceptually. Now once I read this explanation over again and the suggested other posts, then I can drown myself in the "fun" stuff. Cheers.